# iOS warnings GLES-Render and other

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I get 8 warnings in GLES-Render, all of them are about the same thing:

`setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix` is deprecated.

Exactly here:

```
[mShaderProgram setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix];
```

The other warnings are:

Inside of this function:

```
-(void) incrementOffset:(CGPoint)offset forChild:(CCNode*)node
{
    for( unsigned int i=0;i < parallaxArray_->num;i++) {
        CGPointObject *point = parallaxArray_->arr[i];
        if( [[point child] isEqual:node] ) {
            [point setOffset:ccpAdd([point offset], offset)];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The warning is: `Instance method '-child- not found (return type defaults to 'id')`

Also in the library: XMLSupport, in `GDataXMLNode` i get this warning 
 Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type `'const xmlChar *'` (aka 'const unsigned char *')

in this line:

```
NSCAssert1(result == 0, @"GDataXMLNode XPath namespace %@ issue", prefix);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `-setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix` isn't provided by any iOS classes. You must be using a third-party library here. What is mShaderProgram and what provides that?

Comment: As I said, its from the file GLES-Render Which is used by cocos2d and box2d. I have found that that function was only calling other function named setUniformsForBuiltins so what I basically did was change setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix with setUniformsForBuiltins. The other errors I have no idea...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Don't know if this applies to Cocos2d, but in Cocos2d-x I've used `setUniformsForBuiltins`, which seems to do the trick (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/13032?r=22888#message-22888).

Answer (score 6):

Per @conciliator's comment (and the comment on the deprecation in CCGLProgram.h), `setUniformForModelViewProjectionMatrix` is now `setUniformsForBuiltins`

Regarding "instance method child not found"—CGPointObject doesn't appear to be a public interface (it's both declared and defined in CCParallaxNode.m).